# warning C5050 incompatible environments - _UTF8 defined in C++ 20 modules Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, c++20, c++-modules

I am working on a small project to get used to C++20. For the GUI I use Qt 6.5 and I split parts into hopefully meaningful modules.
When building I get multiple warnings of the same kind and currently I am trying to clean up the code. But I realized I don't really understand how to fix the problem yet.

The warning is

> warning C5050: Possible incompatible environment while importing module 'b3m.common': _UTF8 is defined in current command line and not in module command line

And as I said, many of these are for every module consumed (some self-defined and some without a name, I assume these are the modules made out of c++ stl headers). I realized that all these warnings happen in projects inside the GUI-folder, so I assume that Qt sets a certain property that results in this mismatch.

Can someone explain the cause of this warning to me and/or tell me how to properly fix it in my modules to solve these warnings.

In case you need more information, I will try to create a minimal example. The code is public on github, but please don't judge too much, I am about to clean up right now: https://github.com/Tobxon/BBoyBattleManager